Trying to set the HOST CODE PAGE from the command line for IBM i Access Client Solutions
I am currently connecting to a AS400 using the IBM Windows client acslaunch_win-32.exe (part of IBM i Access Client Solutions).  I can pass all the parameters, like server host, protocol, connection ID, that I can set via a profile apart from the "Host Code Page".  I have scoured the IBM Support site but can not find how to set this connection property.  Is it possible and if so how would I do it?  If this is not the correct Stack Site please could somebody let me know the best placed site for this query.
TIA
Jonathan

it will be hardly to find the as400 generation. the client file from  it should be an text file usually where you can edit iirc..
